# Copy license file to bin folder during build

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I have one license(lic) file in my VS Solution.

I have class library and inside class library i have one folder inside that folder i have license file.

When i build the solution i want to copy this license file to `bin` folder.

i tried using `Copy to Output direction` -> `Copy always` , `Build Action` -> `None` but it copies file with folder.

I want only license file should get copied in `bin` folder.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Set Output Direction to Do not copy.

Then you can use Post-build event, something like

```
xcopy "$(ProjectDir)lic.txt" "$(TargetDir)lic.txt*" /y
```

Specify the correct path to your license file and path to target folder.
Pay attention to the mark * (asterisk) - it makes xcopy not ask whether destination is a file or a directory.