# C# - Save app.config file to subfolder when building

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, location, app-config

I am trying to clean up the base directory of my WinForms app's build folder (built in .NET 6 using Visual Studio 2022).  I have already moved the log4net config file to a Config subfolder and changed the call to the AddLog4Net() extension method to reflect this new location.

I am now trying to get the main App.config file (which holds tons of other configuration for this app) to save to that same subfolder during builds.  It is currently being saved to the root directory (and renamed to SomeWinFormsApp.dll.config in the process) and I'm trying to alter this behavior so that file is saved in the Config subfolder instead and get the app to read it from there.

Even if I move the app.config file to the Config subfolder in the project, Visual Studio still creates the renamed copy in the root folder.

Is there a way to automate this during the build process and not have to move it myself every time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy license file to bin folder during build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32652446/copy-license-file-to-bin-folder-during-build)

Comment: The file is already set to do not copy, it looks like Visual Studio treats the App.config file in a special way natively since it holds all configurations and it knows that.

Comment: So then why do you want to stop it from doing that?

Comment: I don't want to stop it, I want to tell it to put it in a subfolder instead of the root of the build directory and tell the app to read from there.  The root is quite cluttered and I'm OCD like that.

Comment: The answer in the linked post suggests using a PostBuild event. Does that work?

Comment: I guess the question boils down to : does the main config file HAVE to be at the root directory or can it somehow be in a subfolder?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508020/give-app-config-another-name-after-build

Comment: It would most likely work but it would still copy the config file to the root, I tried something similar.  I'd like to know if there's some kind of built-in way for Visual Studio to do that natively without post build.

Comment: That post could be the only way of doing this, I'll look into it.  Thanks

Comment: Hi Martin, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider  accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by combining a post-build event with a one liner on the AppDomain :

```
move "$(TargetDir)SomeWinFormsApp.dll.config" "$(TargetDir)Config"

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", "Config//SomeWinFormsApp.dll.config");
```

Do note that in order for this same manipulation to be automated during the publish process, you can add this to the csproj file :

```
<Target Name="PostPublish" AfterTargets="Publish">
    <Exec Command="move &quot;$(PublishDir)SomeWinFormsApp.dll.config&quot; &quot;$(PublishDir)Config&quot;" />
</Target>
```

Seems to work like a charm!